# How can you switch between workbooks in a excel file (key shortcuts only)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have read in many pages that you can do that with CTRL-ALT, but it does not work in my case. I have two excel files open. When I do CTRL-ALT it goes from one file *to the other!!!*  Then it goes somewhere (it is difficult to tell in excel where) and later goes back to the same workbook in the first excel.

It never goes to other workbooks of the first file.

I am using excel 2016.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-for-windows-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to switch between sheets then simply press and hold CTRL and then press the PgUp or PgDn buttons to move from right-to-left or left-to-right.